# MySQL strange problem Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-23 00:00:00'

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I am trying to insert a column with timestamp format. The date is clearly simple:2020-03-23 00:00:00.
I am defining time stamp like this:
`$items['time']= new DateTime("$year-$month-$day $hour:00:00");`
But I receive following error:
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-23 00:00:00' for column 'time' at row 1
I am using Xampp and php.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Provide variables as-is into the query, build datetime value on MySQL side. Or construct and provide the value as string-type, not as DateTime.

Comment: Your question is about MYSQL, but you show only php. Your php is working as expected. I guess you try to fill your sql-column with a wrong format? So what we need is the table def and the code that actually fills the record.

Comment: Try `$dateStr = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $row['last_time']);` and the echo `$dateStr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MySQL, TIME values in 'hh:mm:ss' format, you should use DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.